# Code returns all members and not the members in the role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is the code:

```js
let getMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => {
    return message.guild.roles.fetch('701142571623252018');
}).map(member => {
    return member.user.username;
});
```

It returns all members in the server, but not the members in the specific role, which it is supposed to do.

This is my full code:

```
    const targetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('701142571623252018');
    if (!targetRole) return console.log('No role found')
    const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === targetRole.id)).map(m => m.user.username)

    const players = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#6B238E')
      .setTitle("Players:")
      .setDescription(members);

    message.channel.send(players);
    //console.log(members);
```

Comment: and what is the content of message.guild ?

Comment: what if you map and then filter?

Comment: Would I just switch the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your filter function is not returning whether the member has the role or not: it's returning a Promise which should resolve into a Role, which is interpreted as `true` and so everything passes the filter.

You don't actually need to fetch the role, since you only need to check if that ID is one of the roles from of the member: to do that you can use [`GuildMember.roles.cache.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache), which will return whether the roles collection has a role with that ID.

Here's how you can do it:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.has('701142571623252018'))
  .map(member => member.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and method `collection.some` for check if member has role.

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    const targetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('ROLE ID');
    if (!targetRole) return console.log('No role found')
    const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === targetRole.id)).map(m => m.user.username)
});
```

### V2

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    const targetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('648157497051447317');
    if (!targetRole) return console.log('No role found')
    const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === targetRole.id)).map(m => m.user.username)
    console.log(members)
});

bot.login('TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: When I try to console.log(members), it doesn't do anything

Comment: I check it, its works fine. Are you sure you login you bot and send message ?

Comment: Oh, 1 qestion, you need members who has role ? Or all members without some role ?

Comment: My bad, I was starting the wrong bot lol. It still says everybody and not just the people who have the role.

Comment: I need all of the members who have that specific role

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: So its right answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308398/12590637

You can use this code