# Getting all members from role returns only the Bot and the user sending the command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i am trying to get all of the server members with certain role with the following code

```
                // REMOVE FROM ALL -----------------------------------------------
                if(args[0] == 'removeFromAll'){
                    var role = msg.mentions.roles.first();
                    if(role == null) {
                        Embeds.removeFromAllNoRole(msg)
                        break;
                    }
                    let roleID = role.id;
                    const membersWithRole = msg.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === roleID)).map(m => m)
                    membersWithRole.forEach(member => {
                        member.roles.remove(roleID)
                            .then(function() {
                                console.log(`Removed role from user ${member.user.tag}!`);
                        })
                    })
                    Embeds.removeFromAllFinished(msg)
                }
```

And then remove their roles. This however only removes the role from the bot its self and the user sending the command.

I have tried at least all of these solutions:

[Code returns all members and not the members in the role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308100/code-returns-all-members-and-not-the-members-in-the-role)

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/discord.js+v12.2.0+get+all+members+of+a+role

[How to remove a role from every member of the guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383129/how-to-remove-a-role-from-every-member-of-the-guild)

[How do I list all Members with a Role In Discord.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js)

And none of them haven't worked for me!

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think it has something to do with intents. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) helps you.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca That solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with intents! Here is link to a SOF question with similar problem and how to solve it!

[Discord.js Bot Welcomes Member, Assign a Role and send them a DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684)